# Trouble with bit manipulation in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Alright so I've built a really really simple network sniffer in python that captures IP headers, it returns it in a form of struct, using struct library, I unpack these structs into integers strings or what ever's necessary. now I encounter the following problem, I receive a 20 bytes struct, the 7 & 8 byte, represent a number that needs to be translated into binary code and is 16 bits long. for example: it could be the number 24576, a 16 bits long number, which in binary if translated to 16 bits should be

0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

now, the first three bits: **0 1 1** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 represent flags regarding fragments of the IP header.
the first 3 bits represent flags and the other 13 represent fragment offset,
now my problem is this, when I unpack the struct, and it returns the number for example **24576** when translating it to bin, it takes off unnecessary zero hence the binary is:

1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I have to questions, the first is is it possible to translate a number into bits when I define how long it would be?
for example if I want to translate the decimal number 2 into binary ( which is 10 ) but make it a 16 bits long, so it would be

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

but without using zerofill function, ( I have no idea how long the binary is going to be, )

if not, what's the best way to isolate three first bits out of a number, and how do I execute it in python.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to use shift and mask operations, so for the upper three bits, use a `right shift` operation

```
>>> num = 24576
>>> top = num >> 13
>>> top
3
>>> bin(top)
'0b11'
```

And for the lower 13, just use a mask (bitwise `and` operation)

```
>>> bot = num & 0x1fff
>>> bin(bot)
'0b0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the right format specifier gives you the required zero-padding:

```
>>> '{:016b}'.format(2)
'0000000000000010'
>>> '{:016b}'.format(24576)
'0110000000000000'
```

To check which bits are set and extract them you would use the same approach as in C:

```
>>> num = 24576
>>> for i in range(16):
...     if num & (1 << i):
...         print('Bit ', i, 'is set')
... 
Bit 13  is set
Bit 14  is set
```